# Scatterplot problem in changing points color with if function

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I am new to python, and I am trying to plot some points with different colours. The colour of the points should be decided by a value of the point itself

The dataset is a 3 dimensional matrix, the first two dimension are used for plotting, while the 3rd one is the classification. The points should have different colours based on the classification.

I am using a for loop with an if inside.
Somehow it behaves like all the classification value is -1, printing all the points with that colour, despite printing the value correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = 10

datacord = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,1],[1,3,1],[2,3,1],[5,5,-1],[5,6,-1],[6,5,-1],[7,6,-1],[7,7,-1]])
xaxis = datacord[:,0]
yaxis = datacord[:,1]
dataclass = datacord[:,2]

for f in range (p):   
    if dataclass[f] > 0:
        plt.scatter(xaxis, yaxis, color="blue")
        print(dataclass[f])
    else:
        plt.scatter(xaxis, yaxis, color="red")
        print(dataclass[f])

plt.axis([-1, 10, -1, 10])
plt.show()
```

I would like to understand why the colours does not changes, but are all the same.
I expect the first 5 points to be coloured in blue, while the other 5 to be coloured in red

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basicly put 10 scatters on top of each other, since the last one is red, you can only see the red ones.

If you only want to plot one point in each iteration:

```
for f in range (p):   
    if dataclass[f] > 0:
        plt.scatter(xaxis[f], yaxis[f], color="blue")
        print(dataclass[f])
    else:
        plt.scatter(xaxis[f], yaxis[f], color="red")
        print(dataclass[f])
```